# Iteratively deleting more than one datapoints for linregress Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-itertools

Dataset first/output first:

[image: Dataset]

I need to iteratively delete more than one datapoint so as to get the slope. The comment section says which data points are deleted to get the slope.

The code I use to delete only one datapoint is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df=pd.read_excel('I:/Python/Data/trial.xlsx')

grouped = df.groupby('TestEvent')
df["slope"] = np.NaN
for test_event, g in grouped:
    print('TestEvent: {}'.format(test_event))
    for i in g.index:
        others = g.loc[g.index != i, ["x-axis", "y-axis"]]
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(others)
        print ("slope", slope, 'for data without pair', i)
        df.loc[i, "slope"] = slope

df.to_excel('trial4.xlsx')
```

---

With this code above (n=1), I could get in all 10 slopes since one datapoint was removed at one time.
__
Now I need to remove two datapoints (or n>1), keeping one constant as shown in the image for both the sequences (111 and 112).

Each sequence finally will give 90 slope data points (0,....9 iterated 9 times).

Finally in the output dataframe, it will be 90 slope values per sequence.

In all the final dataframe will have 180 values of slopes (for sequences 111 and 112)

Thanks for reading. Any help on this matter is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` to get a list of the rows to be dropped in each case.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
...
slopes = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Test Event", "Removed 1", "Removed 2", "Slope"])    
for test_event, g in grouped:
    print('TestEvent: {}'.format(test_event))
    for rows_to_drop in combinations(g.index, 2):
        others = g[["x-axis", "y-axis"]].drop(list(rows_to_drop))
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(others)
        print ("slope", slope, 'for data without rows', rows_to_drop)
        slopes.append({"Test Event": test_event,
                    "Removed 1": rows_to_drop[0],
                    "Removed 2": rows_to_drop[1],
                    "Slope": slope}])
```

Note that there will only be 45 unique values per sequence, not 90, because dropping (0, 1) is the same as dropping (1, 0). This stores the slopes in a separate new dataframe.

Comment: thanks for this. It does work very well. I tried to add it to dataframe using df.loc[i, "slope"] = slope method. It does not seem to work. There is no output coming to excel file.

Comment: this code gives out data in jupyter notebook. However, it is not transferring to excel. The first code you shared I could easily convert it to excel for further analysis.

Comment: the slopes data is in a separate dataframe called `slopes`. If you want it all in 1 dataframe you need to decide what shape you want it in, given that there are 45 slopes for each test event.